# Form Element Required based on a condition (Happy.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm attempting to validate a form client-side using Happy.js.

The basic validation works alright, but I've got a slightly more complicated portion I need to validate that it is a bit more complicated.  Essentially, there is a yes/no radio box that, if yes, displays a few more input tags.  These tags should be required ONLY if the radio button is yes, otherwise they don't need to be required.

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?  I was thinking of setting them as non-required, then creating a happy function which will return false if the input is empty AND the radio button is set to Yes.

Something like this:

```
"#input":{
    required: false,
    message: "required",
    test: happy.needed(parameter)
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs say, you can pass `'sometimes'` to `required` which will make Happy always run the test function.

For the test function, we just return the value of jQuery/Zepto `is`.

```
"#input":{
    required: "sometimes",
    message: "Custom message",
    test: function(input){ 
      return $(input).val() !== '' && $('#radioButton').is(':checked');
    }
}
```

The example that they give `happy.email` might be confusing if you're not sure what's happening. Functions in JavaScript are first class, which means you can pass them around like variables.

So if we were to write:

```
var isRadioButtonChecked = function(input) {
  return $(input).val() !== '' && $('#radioButton').is(':checked');
}
```

Then in our validation rules we could write:

```
"#input":{
    required: "sometimes",
    message: "Custom message",
    test: isRadioButtonChecked
}
```

This would be a bit more concise.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation sir.